# How do I run an .exe before an Insert given certain conditions, to update a string and then insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a Message table, with columns:

```
[dbo].[Message], 
    [FileNo]    (int)           NOT NULL
    [Message]   (varchar 4000)
    [Gps]       (varchar 250)
    ....
```

A typical, correct GPS field looks like:

```
Latitude:34.08605753;Longitude:-117.5318326;Altitude:320.0;Address:12233 6th Street, Los Angeles, CA;
```

A typical, *incorrect* GPS field looks like:

```
Latitude:34.08605753;Longitude:-117.5318326;Altitude:320.0;Address:Unavailable;
```

So I need an actual address here.

My solution was to write a small .exe that returns an address given lat and long:

```
ReverseGeocode.exe 34.08605753 -117.5318326
12233 6th Street, Los Angeles, CA
```

So now I want to write a trigger that checks for 'Unavailable;' and if so, calls my program with the Latitude and Longitude coordinates, so I can input an Address:

```
WHERE GPS LIKE '%Unavailable;'
```

What I have so far is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ReverseGeocode]
ON [dbo].[Message]
BEFORE INSERT
...
```

How do I extract the Lat/Long, call the .exe, extract the output from the .exe, and update the entry before the INSERT happens?

Comment: Have you considered rewriting your program as a sql server clr function or stored procedure? This can then be called 'natively' with T-SQL.

Comment: you can use xp_cmdshell to call scripts and executables but I would tend to agree with Kevin H, use SQLCLR if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't you be implementing the reverse geocode in your business logic before inserting into the db? Most places have their db deep inside the network and it is not accessible to the Internet. If they do then there will be a day when it is lock down after a security audit and you'll find that your trigger will fail along with your insert statement

Comment: @TienDinh The problem is the reverse geocoding only works sometimes, earlier in the process. It's unreliable. These messages are coming in from Android tablets and there are even times when they send an empty 'Gps' field to the SQL table. The fix is usually having to restart the tablet, but that's not reasonable with a company that has hundreds of tablets. The trigger's job is to tidy up the data after the tablets fail.